# Assigning values to a public byte array in one line C#

Tags: c#, arrays, public

I am working with a public byte array and would like to assign values, like I assign arrays inside a method, i.e

```
byte[] foo = {0x32, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x00};
```

but when I define the values I am forced to do

```
foo[0] = 0x32;
foo[1] = 0x00;
foo[2] = 0x1E;
foo[3] = 0x00;
```

If I use the first example VS gives an error "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

If it helps any, the array is always 4 bytes.

my code

```
public byte[] SetSpeed = new byte[4];
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (trackBar1.Value == 0)
    {
        try
        {
            stop = true;
            UpdateSThread.Abort();
            Thread.Sleep(350);
        }
        catch { }
        SetSpeed = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
        WriteMem(GetPlayer() + STATUS_OFFSET, SetSpeed);
        label1.Text = "Normal";              
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a short but *complete* example with the failure. I'd expect what you've given to be fine - but not if you're just assigning to `foo` without declaring it.

Comment: your first example compiles (VS2012)

Comment: You still haven't shown the code that wouldn't compile. I *suspect* you were trying `SetSpeed = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }` which *isn't* the same as your original example at all. Additionally, you haven't made it clear whether you really want to create a new array or whether you want to just mutate the existing array.

Comment: the example I put up now is what wont compile.

Comment: I would like to change values in an existing array, but it needs to be accessible by other methods.

Comment: @user2340475: Finally. That's what *should* have been in the question to start with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first example is fine but it **may only be used in a declaration**. The elements must be implicitly convertible to the element type. The size is determined from the number of elements given.

```
byte[] foo = { 0x32, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x00 };
```

Alternatively you can also d this

```
byte[] foo = new byte[4];
foo[0] = 0x32;
foo[1] = 0x00;
foo[2] = 0x1E;
foo[3] = 0x00;
```

as stated above that the syntax that you are trying to use can only be used in a declaration. so try like this.

```
public byte[] SetSpeed;
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (trackBar1.Value == 0)
    {
        try
        {
            stop = true;
            UpdateSThread.Abort();
            Thread.Sleep(350);
        }
        catch { }

        //note it will always create a new array
        SetSpeed = new byte[]{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}; 
        WriteMem(GetPlayer() + STATUS_OFFSET, SetSpeed);
        label1.Text = "Normal";              
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no *need* to do this though - the original code compiles anyway.

Comment: Thank you, this works, I guess I came across to vague, the public tag was relevant, but removed. no worries, I got my answer

Answer (score 7):

You can only use the form where you don't specify `new` when you're *declaring* a variable. So this is fine:

```
byte[] x = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

But this isn't:

```
byte[] x;
x = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Instead you need something like:

```
byte[] x;
x = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Or for cases where type inference works in your favour and you're using C# 3 or higher, you can use an implicitly typed array:

```
string[] x;
x = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
```

However, you really need to decide whether you *want* to create a new array, or whether you want to mutate the existing array. Given that you're just setting all the values to 0, you could instead use:

```
Array.Clear(SetSpeed, 0, 4);
```

EDIT: Now that the question contains this:

> I would like to change values in an existing array,

then using

```
SetSpeed = new byte[] { ... }
```

is *not* appropriate, as that will change the value of `SetSpeed` to refer to a *different* array.

To update an existing array, you could either just stick with the 4 separate statements, or perhaps extract it to a separate method with 4 parameters. It's not really clear what the values are going to be, which makes it hard to give you the best possible code.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on the Array.Clear, the next tick on the track bar, does start adding values > 0.

Comment: @user2340475: But you still need to decide on whether you want a new array or not. Does anything else have a reference to the array already?

Comment: It is either `Array.Clear(SetSpeed, 0, 4);` or `((IList<byte>)SetSpeed).Clear();`.

Comment: No it does not, when the track bar moves off 0, A thread is started to loop update the value in memory, the value being SetSpeed, when brought back to 0 the thread is exited and the value in memory is set back to 4 bytes of 0

Comment: @user2340475: So what actually needs it as an array other than the method itself? It looks like you could just create it before calling WriteMem.

Comment: 'void UpdateSpeed()
        {
            stop = false;
            while (stop == false)
            {
                if (ReadMem(GetPlayer() + STATUS_OFFSET, 4) != SetSpeed)
                {
                    WriteMem(GetPlayer() + STATUS_OFFSET, SetSpeed);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(300);
            }

        } not sure how to display this as code. but that is the thread that is started.

Comment: @user2340475: Well you're comparing a byte array with a reference comparison there, so that's unlikely to work either... and unless `stop` is volatile, you may well not see changes from another thread...

Answer (score 0):

The example given

```
byte[] foo = new byte[] { 0x32, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x00 };
```

doesn't assign values to an *existing* `byte[]`: rather, it replaces the reference with a reference to a *new* `byte[]`. Without more context, this approach may (or may not work), for instance the public `byte[]` may be readonly, i.e.:

```
public byte[] Foo { get ; private set ; }
```

What you can do is to use the static overloads of `Array.Copy()`:

```
byte[] newBytes = GetSomeBytes() ;
Array.Copy( newBytes , Foo , Foo.Length ) ;
```

Or you could write an extension method (which might wrap `Array.Copy` should you so desire):

```
public static CopyFrom<T>( this T[] target , int offset , params T[] source )
{
  foreach ( T value in values )
  {
     // Throws IndexOutOfRangeException if offset exceeds destination length
     target[offset++] = value ; 
  }
}
```

which will let you do things like:

```
public byte[] Foo { get ; private set ; }
.
.
.
Foo.CopyFrom( 0, 1,2,3,4 ) ;
.
.
.
Foo.CopyFrom( 1, new byte[]{1,2} ) ;
```